# Ошибка сокетов: D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM

Tags: android

Пишу сокет-клиент. Вроде всё делаю правильно...

```
tvOut.setText("Коннектимся...");
Log.d("my", "Коннектимся...");
try {
    InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.121");
    Log.d("my", "InetAddress serverAddr...");
    socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 3426);
    Log.d("my", "socket = new Socket...");
...
```

Logcat выдаёт:

```
12-11 00:16:36.605: D/my(1247): Коннектимся...
12-11 00:16:36.675: D/my(1247): InetAddress serverAddr...
12-11 00:16:36.715: D/AndroidRuntime(1247): Shutting down VM
```

Что тут не так?

Comment: а там дальше в логе ничего нет? может какие то ещё строки?

и можно попробовать try-catch добавить (я не уверен, что поможет, но попробовать можно).

- в манифест файле все в порядке?
- надеюсь, не с главного треда запускаете (если андроид 3.1 и старше)?

Comment: спасибо разобрался... засунул в поток:     Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           try {
  socket = new Socket("192.168.1.121", 3426);